# AppBuilder VS Plugin for Open Source NativeScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, telerik, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

The plugin for NativeScript for Visual Studio support ([mentioned here](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/nativescript/getting-started-ns/get-started-vse)) is part of AppBuilder, which is not inherently free.  There is no documentation that really explains whether a license for AppBuilder is required to use it, or if that also supports open source.

Does anybody know if the plugin mentioned in the link above is supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Telerik Platform (which includes AppBuilder) tools and services are paid, but come with a 30 day free trial. And yes this is the case if you are developing with NativeScript or Cordova.

If you want to go 100% free, you can use the [NativeScript CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript).

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to figure out what the best setup to build an app in Visual Studio 2015 would be....  I'm thinking the new ASP.NET 5 with bower/npm/gulp/grunt support, as it will naturally support these new conventions. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, there is nothing stopping you from developing an app with Visual Studio but using the NativeScript CLI for builds etc. Not as slick as using a paid version of the AppBuilder extension, but it will certainly work!